# How can i sort the dictionary using keys in c#---Is it possible using LINQ?

Tags: c#

```
    Dictionary<string,string> l_dictData = new Dictionary<string,string>
```

the above dictionary contains data like this:

```
    (1)key = "4" value"122"
    (2)key = "8" value"1772"
    (3)key = "0" value"166"
```

Required output:

```
   (1)key = "0" value"166"
   (2)key = "4" value"122"
   (3)key = "8" value"1772"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how do you want further process the resulting expression (do you want to just print it out ?), it might help to just sort the key value pairs by the key :

```
foreach(var kvp in l_dictData.OrderBy(k => k.Key))
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("key = {0}, value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: dear Thomas,
         foreach statement takes more time..r u accepting it?..I am also using the same...

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between performance concerning foreach vs. Linq, it's more of a readability and functional approach question. IF you just want to sort it at one place but in 10 other places you don't care about order, it seems like a best way to go for me.

Answer (score 6):

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is inherently unsorted - or at least, the order isn't guaranteed.

[`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) and [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) are both maps which are sorted by key when you iterate over them. They differ in implementation: `SortedList<,>` is implemented as a sorted list of key/value pairs, whereas `SortedDictionary<,>` is a red/black tree. Both have O(log n) search times instead of the O(1) for `Dictionary<,>` (assuming a decent hash), and other performance complexity measures are different too - the docs for both `SortedList<,>` and `SortedDictionary<,>` give details of the different trade-offs between the two.

You can pass in a custom `IComparer<T>` to determine how the keys should be ordered, but the ordering is *always* done on key, *never* on value. It looks like that shouldn't be a problem in the case you've given - although if the keys are actually string values of numbers, you should consider how you want keys "1", "11" and "2" to be ordered...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `SortedList<string,string>`